# How to append error message to an error message field staging table in ssis

Tags: ssis, append, isnull

In my SSIS package I have 4 execute sql tasks to get a result.  If the result is null on any of the 4 tasks, I want to put a error message in my error message filed on the same row indicating which filed(s) are NULL. I cant find any examples of the same.

Comment: You mean if a task doesn't generate any rows?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this works? I am confused on ` I want to put a error message in my error message filed on the same row indicating which filed(s) are NULL` would work

Comment: You could add a derived column to your data flow. As expression for this derived column you add something like this: `(ISNULL(@[User::Variable1]) || ISNULL( @[User::Variable2])) ? "ErrorText : ""` where Variable1 and Variable2 (and 3 and 4 when you added them) represent the results of your 4 tasks...